# Using raw input to remove elements of a list in python

Tags: python, list

Say I have a list like this:

```
[['14632','apples'],
['134','oranges'],
['834','bananas'],
['472','tomatoes']]
```

I'm trying to remove an item (for example, ['134', 'oranges']) when a user inputs 'oranges' as an argument in a function. This is my code so far:

```
def remove_item(my_list, name):
    name = raw_input()
    for item in my_list:
        if name == item[1]:
            my_list.remove(item)
```

where item[0] is the number, and item[1] is the string. This code doesn't work, and I missing something to do with remove, or am I using '==' wrong?

Comment: What problem do you have?

Comment: It seems to work just well. But you don't need to pass `name` as parameter since you are asking it from the user inside the function.

Comment: Hamatti's right. Tested it works fine

Comment: Don't remove elements from a data structure while iterating over it - you will not get the correct result. Create a new list and add the elements you want rather than removing from the existing list.

Comment: The only problem could be, if there are two consecutive `oranges`, only the first one will be removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modifying a list that you are looping through, by inserting or deleting an element, is generally risky. In Python, deleting the current element makes the for-loop skip the next item. The Python manual recommends that in this case you iterate through a copy of the list.

*From Python 3.1.3 documentation - compount statements - 8.3 the `for` statement:*

> Note There is a subtlety when the sequence is being modified by the
>   loop (this can only occur for mutable sequences, i.e. lists). An
>   internal counter is used to keep track of which item is used next, and
>   this is incremented on each iteration. When this counter has reached
>   the length of the sequence the loop terminates. This means that if the
>   suite deletes the current (or a previous) item from the sequence, the
>   next item will be skipped (since it gets the index of the current item
>   which has already been treated). Likewise, if the suite inserts an
>   item in the sequence before the current item, the current item will be
>   treated again the next time through the loop. This can lead to nasty
>   bugs that can be avoided by making a temporary copy using a slice of
>   the whole sequence, e.g.,
>
> ```
> for x in a[:]:
>     if x < 0: a.remove(x)
> ```

Comment: Thanks, the problem was I was printing the list at the same time it was being modified, it's all good now

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
def remove_item(my_list, name):
    return [item for item in my_list if item[1] == name]
```